# i am not able to create instance, getting an error

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle19c

I was trying to create SID,

I wrote
: oradim -new -sid newcap

but this command is not creating my instance.

I'm getting error:

DIM-00019: create service error
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.

Comment: Please consider adding more details and context to increase clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the command from a shell started with the "run as administrator" option?

Comment: yeah it worked thanks, also i did not started my DBCA service.